# Xamarin.iOS : round corner effect not working after updating Xamarin Form version to 5.0

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

i recently updated Xamarin form version to 5.0. After updating all the round effect corners are not working inside the App . We are currently using RoundCornersEffect. Below is the code reference.

```
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(RoundCornersEffect), "RoundCornersEffect")]
namespace Org.Code.iOS.Effects
{
    public class RoundCornersEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            try
            {
                PrepareContainer();
                SetCornerRadius();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {              
                Debug.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
            try
            {
                Container.Layer.CornerRadius = new nfloat(0);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.PropertyName == RoundCornersSharedEffect.CornerRadiusProperty.PropertyName)
                SetCornerRadius();
        }

        private void PrepareContainer()
        {
            Container.ClipsToBounds = true;
            Container.Layer.AllowsEdgeAntialiasing = true;
            Container.Layer.EdgeAntialiasingMask = CAEdgeAntialiasingMask.All;
        }

        private void SetCornerRadius()
        {
            var cornerRadius = RoundCornersSharedEffect.GetCornerRadius(Element);
            Container.Layer.CornerRadius = new nfloat(cornerRadius);
        }
    }
}
```

And we have RoundCornersSharedEffect like this.

```
namespace Org.Code.Effects
{
    public class RoundCornersSharedEffect : RoutingEffect
    {
        public RoundCornersSharedEffect() : base("App.RoundCornersEffect")
        {
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty CornerRadiusProperty =
            BindableProperty.CreateAttached(
                "CornerRadius",
                typeof(int),
                typeof(RoundCornersSharedEffect),
                0,
                propertyChanged: OnCornerRadiusChanged);

        public static int GetCornerRadius(BindableObject view) =>
            (int)view.GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty);

        public static void SetCornerRadius(BindableObject view, int value) =>
            view.SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, value);

        private static void OnCornerRadiusChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            if (!(bindable is View view))
                return;

            var cornerRadius = (int)newValue;
            var effect = view.Effects.OfType<RoundCornersSharedEffect>().FirstOrDefault();

            if (cornerRadius > 0 && effect == null)
                view.Effects.Add(new RoundCornersSharedEffect());

            if (cornerRadius == 0 && effect != null)
                view.Effects.Remove(effect);
        }
    }
}
```

Please suggest how to resolve this round corner effect issue.

Comment: This part where you add and remove effect is likely to cause the problem.

Comment: If it used to work, then perhaps it needs Rebuild Solution. if that doesn't fix it, find your project's "bin" and "obj" folders, delete them. This ensures everything gets fully rebuilt.

Comment: I tried rebuilding the solution by deleting "bin" and "obj" folders. But still the issue exists. I observed SetCornerRadius is not getting called.

Comment: None of the RoundCornersEffect methods are getting called after upgrading to version 5.0

Answer (score 0):

Use it above the namespace of your **iOS->RoundCornersEffect** class

```
[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("App")]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(xxx.iOS.RoundCornersEffect), nameof(xxx.iOS.RoundCornersEffect))]
```

**xxx.iOS.RoundCornersEffect** Is the class you created in iOS(Change xxx to your project name).

For more information, please refer to the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/reusable-roundeffect#create-a-shared-routingeffect).

Comment: Is the problem solved?